# Is This Summation Expression Equivalent to the Conditional Probability ($ P_{Z|X} $)?

Tags: calculus, probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I have encountered an expression in my studies and am trying to determine if it correctly represents the conditional probability ($ P_{Z|X}(z|x) $). The expression is as follows:

$$
\sum_{s \in S} P_S(s) P_{Z|S,X}(z|s,x)
$$

In this expression, ($ P_S(s) $) seems to denote the probability of ( s ) in set ( S ), and ($ P_{Z|S,X}(z|s,x) $) is the conditional probability of ($ Z $) given ($ S $) and ($ X $).

My question is: Does the above summation indeed yield ($ P_{Z|X}(z|x) $), and under which conditions or assumptions would this be accurate?

Any insight or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: First, $S,X,Z$ seem to be random variables. If $S$ and $X$ are independent, then sure the above cancells out $S.$ However, this won't be the case in general.

Comment: @WilliamM.thank yiu, ciuld i ask for proof for second case.

Comment: Expand everything out and use that $P(S=s,X=x)=P(S=s)P(X=x).$